# HTML5 Video on iPad 2/3/Mini

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video

The website I've designed has a full-screen HTML5 video. Recently we've realised that some iPad devices don't display the video at all - just a small black box instead.

The video itself is H.264 - (MPEG-4 AVC) with an AAC audio track.

Strangely this video issue is restricted to iPad 3, iPad 4 and iPad Mini (1st generation) devices. Every other platform and browser combination I've tested plays the video just fine - including other iPads and iOS devices (iPad 2, iPad Air, for example).

Any ideas why the video does not appear on these devices?

This is the code I've used to embed the video on the page:

```
<style>
    #videoContainer { position: relative; width: 100%; }
    #siteVideo { width: 100%; }
</style>

<div id="videoContainer">
    <video id="siteVideo" autoplay loop muted poster="video-poster.jpg" src='new-movie.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
</div>
```

Comment: h.264 should work try <iframe> instead

Comment: What's the H.264 profile of the video - base, main or high? You can discover the profile by running avprobe agains the file or using [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) or a similar tool. Old devices support only base and maybe main.